Playwright Python: 'retain-on-failure'
For Node.js it's mentioned option 'retain-on-failure' (https://playwright.dev/docs/videos) to preserve only videos for failed tests. Nothing similar for the Python. How can it be solved (delete videos for passed tests)? Thanks
import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def browser(headless):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=headless)
        yield browser
        browser.close()

@pytest.fixture
def context(browser):
    context = browser.new_context(
        record_video_dir="reports/",
        record_video_size={"width": 1024, "height": 768},
    )
    yield context
    context.close()

@pytest.fixture
def page(context):
    page = context.new_page()
    yield page
    page.close()


Solved with a hook
# tests\conftest.py
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # Execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_call", rep)

# fixtures\fixture_base.py
@pytest.fixture
def page(context, request):
    page = context.new_page()
    yield page
    video_path = page.video.path()
    page.close()
    if request.node.rep_call.outcome == "passed":
        time.sleep(1) # to prevent failure on a locked state for the file
        os.remove(video_path)

